# Parse.com add JSON Object to JSON Array

Tags: java, android, json, mongodb, parse-platform

My problem is simple, I'd like to add a `JSONObject` to a `JSONArray` that I store in a MongoDB database. I can easily add all types of data like `Strings`, `Ints` etc but not `JSONObjects`.
I do this in my code :

```
public void done(ParseObject lan, ParseException e) {
    if(e==null){
       JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
       try{                                                   
            object.put("PlayerName","John");
            object.put("ID",514145);                                                  
            lan.add("Participants",object); //nothing gets inserted
            lan.add("Participants",15); //works fine
            lan.add("Participants",JSONObject.null); //works fine too
          }catch (JSONException error){

          }

          lan.increment("Number");
          lan.saveInBackground();
   }else{
          Log.i("Parse Error","error");
   }
}
```

But nothing appears in my db and there's no error thrown.
Do you guys have any clue on how to do that ?

Comment: Can you try `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();   jsonArray.put(object);    jsonArray.put(15);    jsonArray.put(JSONObject.null);    lan.put("Participants",jsonArray)`  instead of directly adding to `ParseObject` ?

Comment: I tried that already but in my case I want to be able to add multiple object to my array. If I do that it will replace the array with a new one...

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure why the way you've in post doesn't work. Is there a way you can get `JSONArray jsonArray = getExistingArrayFromParseObject;` and then add the new entries.

Comment: Yes I do this : `JSONArray jsonArray = lan.getJSONArray("Participants"); where lan is the parseObject that I get from a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `object.toString()` instead of `object`.

```
lan.add("Participants", object.toString());
```

**JSON:**

```
{"Participants":["{\"PlayerName\":\"John\",\"ID\":514145}"]}
```

**To parse this JSON try this:**

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(YOUR_JSON_STRING);

// Participants
JSONArray participantsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Participants");

// Participant
JSONObject participanJsonObject = participantsJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

// PlayerName
String playerName = participanJsonObject.getString("PlayerName");
// ID
String id = participanJsonObject.getInt("ID");
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Okay thanks that is working but in the DB it looks like this : "{\"PlayerName\":\"John\",\"ID\":514145}". It's not really clean !

Comment: If my answer seems useful then please give an upvote. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Last question : why can't we just send a JSONObject to the database ? It would be much easier to retrieve it afterwards no ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert that Json Object into String and store it in string format

```
lan.add("Participants",object.toString());
```

And when you want to use that you can easily convert it into Json Object again like this

```
JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject("Your Json String");
```

Comment: Okay thanks that is working but in the DB it looks like this : "{\"PlayerName\":\"John\",\"ID\":514145}". It's not really clean !

Comment: Try converting it back and check if you get the same object

Comment: But how do you retrieve it ?  In the database it's like this :  "Participants": [
        "{\"PlayerName\":\"John\",\"ID\":514145}"
    ],

Comment: I have already mention in my answer how to convert back into object

Comment: Yes I can see that but my JSONObject is in the array and has no "name". So how would you do that in my case ?